# Can my surname under which I publish differ from the one on my passport?

Tags: publications, personal-name

Can my surname under which I publish differ from the one on my passport?

I was thinking of publishing under "Miller-Hendrix" instead of just "Miller".

Comment: I know several people whose surnames on their passport differ, at least slightly, from the one they publish under (married women who publish under their maiden names because they started their career that way; people whose surnames are long and difficult for English speakers to remember; people whose passports have suboptimal transliterations from Cyrillic into English). If you have a good reason to use a different surname, go ahead. If you don't have a good reason, it's remotely possible it will cause difficulties (e.g. when traveling to conferences in Israel), so I'd advise against it.

Comment: You can, but it might not be a good choice on the long run of things.

Comment: Preferably (if that is possible in your country) try to get the name you want to publish under listed as a pseudonym on your passport.

Comment: +1. @TheFireGuy Related to your comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8603/if-i-publish-under-a-pseudonym-can-i-still-take-credit-for-my-work?rq=1 (Thanks)